# How to pass variable from main pipeline to child pipeline in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have set variable "Id" in main pipeline and I'm setting value in "Set Variable 1"
I would like to pass variable to child pipeline. I have created parameter "Id" in child pipeline.
However I cannot refer to @{variables('id')} in Lookup5 of Child pipeline.

How to pass correctly variable?

Main pipeline:
[image: Main pipeline]

Child pipeline:
[image: Child pipeline]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to pass the variable into the parameters of child pipeline.
[image]

Simply access the passed in parameter with `@{pipeline().parameters.Id}` in the child pipeline.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure has a added a functionality to return parameter to the child pipeline using set variable activity.
[image]

Here is the Azure Data Factory document link: **[Configure Pipeline Return Value in Child Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-return-value#configure-pipeline-return-value-in-child-pipeline)**

Or You can through a video for the quick help: **[How to Pass Values between Two ADF Pipelines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWsoF72tuhg)**